MudSelect arrow button clicked open but no items in the dropdown list after a certain delay
In my blazor-server side application, i am having difficulty trying to figure out why when i click on a dropdown-list (MudSelect) the arrow button sometimes opens and there is no dropdown-list with items and after a certain delay the dropdown-list appears.
Here is the image of what it looks like when the arrow button is clicked(open) but no dropdown-list.

I would appreciate for any help.
I have tried this
`<MudItem xs="12" sm="6">
    @if (IsLoading)
    {
        <MudSkeleton Width="100%" Height="56px" Animation="Wave" />
    }
    else
    {
        <MudSelect T="int" ValueChanged="OnProgramChange" Value="DemandModel.ToProgramId"
                   Label="Identifiant"
                   Variant="Variant.Text" ReadOnly="ReadOnly"
                   For="@(() => DemandModel.ToProgramId)">
            <MudSelectItem Value="0">@(string.Empty)</MudSelectItem>
            @foreach (var program in EnumState.Programs)
            {
                <MudSelectItem Value="@program.Id">
                    @(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?.Name == "fr-FR" ? program.NameFr : program.NameEn)
                </MudSelectItem>
            }
        </MudSelect>
    }
</MudItem>

@code {
    private bool IsLoading = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        await GetProgramsAsync();
        IsLoading = false;
     
    }
`

I still have no effect on when the list is no empty when i click the arrow on the MudSelect.

Firstly, I create a new sample and use the latest MudBlazor package and check the MudSelect component, everything works well. So, can you tell us which version of MudBlazor package are you using? Try to create a new app and use the latest MudBlazor to test it.

i am having difficulty trying to figure out why when i click on a
dropdown-list (MudSelect) the arrow button sometimes opens and there
is no dropdown-list with items and after a certain delay the
dropdown-list appears.

Second, for this issue, I suggest you check and try the followings:

The application render mode.
Whether you are using ServerPrerendered or Server render mode. As we all known, using the ServerPrerendered render mode, the OnInitializedAsync method will execute twice. So, try to use the Server render mode in the _Host.cshtml.

Refer to Prerendering.

Ensure the State Has Changed After Data Load.
Calling the StateHasChanged(); in the OnInitializedAsync method:
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
     IsLoading = true;
     await GetProgramsAsync();
     IsLoading = false;
     StateHasChanged(); // Add this line to trigger re-render after data load
 }


Use MudSelect Disabled Property During Loading.
 <MudSelect T="int" ValueChanged="OnProgramChange" Value="DemandModel.ToProgramId"
            Label="Identifiant"
            Variant="Variant.Text" ReadOnly="ReadOnly"
            Disabled="@(IsLoading)"
            For="@(() => DemandModel.ToProgramId)">
     <MudSelectItem Value="0">@(string.Empty)</MudSelectItem>
     @foreach (var program in EnumState.Programs)
     {
         <MudSelectItem Value="@program.Id">
             @(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture?.Name == "fr-FR" ? program.NameFr : program.NameEn)
         </MudSelectItem>
     }
 </MudSelect>



Finally, using the above methods, if the problem is still not resolved, you can create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem and share with us.

I am using MudBlazor Version="6.10.0". And i am using Server render mode.
I still have the problem, i am trying to reproduce the issues with a minimal sample project.
